# Javascript <script> tag without `async` loaded asynchronously

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, asynchronous, magento-1.9, script-tag

We have a script that our customers can put on their site in order to insert a form.

The script is included simply like this:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ourdomain.com/script.js"></script>`
Since the script uses `document.write`, it cannot be loaded asynchronously.

One of our customers is complaining that their browser is giving the following error message: "Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened" and maintains that they have not altered the `<script>` tag in any way (so no `async` added).

Is it somehow possible that a `<script>` **without** an `async` attribute is still loaded asynchronously?

This occurs on a Magento 1.9 website with Chrome browsers.

Comment: I'd say no, that's not possible. How certain are you that there's not something unusual about the way this one particular customer is loading your script?

Comment: I bet your customer is injecting the `<script>` tag itself dynamically.

Comment: No, If neither async or defer is present, the script is fetched and executed immediately. If your script has been proven to work on previous integrations, maybe it's worthwile to check out how this customer has been integrating it. Ask them how they load your scripts -
 I follow @MikaelLennholm that they might load it through code...

Comment: Just wondering. Why use `document.write` at all. There are other ways of accomplishing the same thing that will work with asynchronously as well as synchronously loaded scripts. In this way you would free up your customers to load your script any way they choose.